# How to group a datatable by month and count the rows that falls under that month

Tags: c#, .net, linq, datatable

I'm trying to create a line chart using a datatable that has all the data that I need but I can't seem to group it successfully.

I need to group the datatable by month/year and count all the records that fall within each respective month/year.

I actually tried to extract the data and make the graph in excel. So it should look like this.

[image: ![enter image description here]

Ignore the quarters as those are auto generated by excel

Here's the code:

```
var chartResults = (from myrow in chartInstruction.Chart.AsEnumerable()
                    group myrow by new
                    {
                        series = myrow.Field<string>(chartInstruction.Series),
                        xaxis = myrow.Field<DateTime>(chartInstruction.Xaxis).ToShortDateString() 
                    }
                into g
                    select new
                    {
                        Field = g.Key,
                        Total = g.Count()
                    }).ToArray();

string[] xAxis = chartResults.Select(x => x.Field.xaxis).Distinct().OrderBy(x => x).ToArray();
string[] series = chartResults.Select(x => x.Field.series).Distinct().OrderBy(x => x).ToArray();
var seriesInfo = new List<SeriesInfo>();
foreach (string s in series)
{
    var tmp = new List<double>();
    foreach (string xx in xAxis)
    {
        var found = chartResults.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Field.xaxis == xx && x.Field.series == s);
        tmp.Add(found?.Total ?? 0);
    }
    seriesInfo.Add(new SeriesInfo { Name = s, Series = tmp.ToArray() });
}
```

Comment: Send your data model, sample data and what are you expect, please.

Comment: Try following :             var chartResults = chartInstruction.Chart.AsEnumerable()
                .GroupBy(myrow => new DateTime(
                    myrow.Field<DateTime>(chartInstruction.Xaxis).Year,
                    myrow.Field<DateTime>(chartInstruction.Xaxis).Month,
                    1))
                .Select(x => new { month = x.Key, count = x.Count() }).ToList();